# How to save user inputs in a for loop as an integer and string

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, user-input

A user wants to input data like below and save N as list of integers and B as a list of strings.

Input:

```
2
hello world
3
how are you
5
what are you doing man
```

Then I want to save these two lists like below:

```
N=[2,3,5]
B=['hello world','how are you','what are you doing man']
```

I started with code below but I man not sure how put it in a loop to save all of them.

```
N=list(map(int, input()))
B = list(map(str, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
N, B = lists = [], []

for i in range(6):
    lists[i%2].append(input())

N = list(map(int, N))
```

Or, maybe less cryptic:

```
aux = [input() for _ in range(6)]

N = list(map(int, aux[::2]))
B = aux[1::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is very simple and explicit.  A `while` loop can be used to keep the prompts rolling, until an exist command (in this case : `x`) is given.

Example:

```
N, B = [], []

while True:
    print('Enter an integer, then string (or [x] to exit):')
    n = input()
    if n != 'x':
        N.append(int(n))
        B.append(input())
    else:
        break
```

Prompts:

```
Enter an integer, then string (or [x] to exit):
5
Hello.
Enter an integer, then string (or [x] to exit):
15
How are you?
Enter an integer, then string (or [x] to exit):
20
Very well, thank you.
Enter an integer, then string (or [x] to exit):
x
```

Output:

```
N
>>> [5, 15, 20]

B
>>> ['Hello.', 'How are you?', 'Very well, thank you.']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a real-time python notepad:

```
N = []
B = []
i = 0
while True:
    lst = B if i % 2 else N
    i += 1
    text = input()
    lst.append(text)
    if lst:
        if not text and not lst[-1]:
            lst.pop()
            break
N = list(map(int, N))
print(N)
print(B)
```

Simply run the above code, and type until you press ENTER without other characters twice.
Input:

```
2
hello world
3
how are you
5
what are you doing man
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5]
['hello world', 'how are you', 'what are you doing man']
```